# iOS App Verified Anchor Link Allowing to Call or Text

Tags: html, ios, iphone, xcode

I have a list of phone numbers on my iOS App - all consisting of a simple table layout, with the normal `<a href="tel:123-123-1234">123-123-1234</a>` syntax. However, one of the phone numbers has a different menu popping up within my iOS App - in that, it's showing a verified number and allowing a user to text or call the number.

Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]